# Why do Stargates in the Destiny Network Show Instability When Looping on Themselves Through Time?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

If I recall correctly, in the Stargate Universe Episode "Time", the gate shows instability due to the wormhole passing through a nearby star's solar flare.

However, **no other episodes** I watched involving time travel through the stargate **showed instability** when the wormhole passed through a solar flare.

Answer (score 6):

While no cannon explanation is offered, one can infer that the reason lies in the primitive, and utilitarian nature of the Destiny Gate System, as opposed to the Destiny's gate itself and the newer Milky Way and Pegasus gate systems.

It is likely that as time progressed, the Ancients refined their manufacturing techniques, equipment, and gained experience and understanding with their original stargate network (of which the Destiny Gate System is likely based upon) they had eliminated the issue altogether.

> **NOTE:** Keep in mind that Ancients implemented strict controls, which were "built into" the stargate network protocols, thereby
>   preventing such situations as time travel through wormholes on typical
>   travels through a stargate.

Answer (score 0):

Really comes down to Universe Stargates are millions of years older and more primitive than the Milky Way and Pegasus gates.  Also they are not as sophisticated, not used to create a galaxy spanning network, but a used as short range re-supply stations.